# iOS9.0.2 Safari601.1でAudioContext-BufferSourceを再生するには

Tags: javascript, html5

タイトルのバージョンの実機を使って、以下のページで音声が再生できるか確認したところ、音声が再生されません。

> [AndroidとiOSで音を鳴らす - jsdo.it/@59naga](http://jsdo.it/59naga/mobileAudio)（[Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20191017110711/http://jsdo.it/59naga/mobileAudio)）

**touchstart直後にplayを実行しないと音声は無効にされる**、という以前の仕様が変更になったのでしょうか？